# Any way to create Here Documents that substitute some variables but not others in bash?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, here-document

I was wondering if there any way to create a here document in bash to output to a file within a script, problem is that in this config file I am trying to output some variables that start with $ I want to substitute, while others I do not.

Let me illustrate:

```
cat >> /opt/apache2/sites-available/$WEBSITENAME <<END-OF-FILE
 ServerName $WEBSITENAME #This I want to replace


<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName $WEBSITENAME # And this
 ServerAlias *.xxx.com

RedirectMatch /(.*) https://$WEBSITENAME/$1 # But not the $1 here

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is one of many examples, I have many other config files that I want to substitute variables in, but they themselves have many variables of their own, so I don't want to substitute those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape the `$`, forcing bash to treat it as a literal character rather than the start of a variable.

You do this with the backslash (`\`) character.

So use this,:

```
RedirectMatch /(.*) https://$WEBSITENAME/\$1
```

in the here document.